# Travelling with two passports (same name) - which passport should be used for booking?

Tags: passports, china, dual-nationality, uk-citizens

I need advice for my family's itinerary: China - Indonesia - UK - China. My kids have Chinese and UK passports. Can I book their tickets using only their Chinese passports? Exiting China with the Chinese passport seems straightforward, but I'm unsure about Indonesia to the UK. Can we collect the tickets using the chinese passport and show the UK passport at check-in, or should I book the Indonesia to UK flight with the UK passport details? Finally, for the UK to China flight, should we use the Chinese passport for check-in?

Comment: Thanks. I saw that, but it doesn't seem to address this. I think the closest on there is the suggestion to fly via a country that does not require a visa, but Indonesia does require a visa.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I book their tickets using only their Chinese passports?

Yes. The passport provided for booking is mostly for identification purposes. It does not need to be the passport you travel on, which is determined at check in.

> Exiting China with the Chinese passport seems straightforward,

Correct.

> but I'm unsure about Indonesia to the UK. Can we collect the tickets using the chinese passport and show the UK passport at check-in,

Yes

> or should I book the Indonesia to UK flight with the UK passport details?

That would certainly be the easiest if its a separate ticket.

> Finally, for the UK to China flight, should we use the Chinese passport for check-in?

Yes